# Java - I want to read a file name from command line then use a bufferedreader to read each line

Tags: java, command-line, bufferedreader

I'm getting an eclipse red underline error on the

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
```

line on "inFile".  This is the object that I would like to read which I believe contains the command line filename/path that I give it on the command line.  Am I handling this wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
      if (0 < args.length) {
          File inFile = new File(args[0]);
      }

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } 

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare inFile outside of the if block

Comment: close `}` for `if` just before `}` of the `main` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (0 < args.length) {
    File inFile = new File(args[0]);
}
```

to this:

```
File inFile = null;
if (0 < args.length) {
   inFile = new File(args[0]);
} else {
   System.err.println("Invalid arguments count:" + args.length);
   System.exit();
}
```

because the `file` variable is not accessible outside the `if/else` statement.

I've added in the `else` (for the case when no `args` are provided) a friendly message saying the the argument count was invalid and exit for the program.

Comment: So adding the else statement now gives a larger scope to inFile? Or you did that just to give the user better knowledge of the args error?

Comment: No, defining the `inFile` outside of the `if/else` statement gives larger scope (the scope is within the `main` method)

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I think you can take out the "File" inside the if statement now as you have already declared inFile as such outside the if, other than that I think that's good.

Comment: Correct, missed to fix that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

inFile is declared in the if statement.  As such, it's scope ends at line 11;

Answer (score 1):

The variable `inFile` loses scope outside of the if block:

```
  if (0 < args.length) {
      File inFile = new File(args[0]);
  }
```

Change to:

```
  File inFile = null;
  if (0 < args.length) {
      inFile = new File(args[0]);
      // Make sure the file exists, can read, etc...
  }
  else
  {
    // Do something if a required parameter is not provided...
  }
```

Comment: Note that one must take care as to scope and associated synchronization considerations of File variable in question. Limit to encapsulated method as best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable, `inFile`, is local to the containing if-block.

Perhaps this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      File inFile = null;

      if (0 < args.length) {
          inFile = new File(args[0]);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the 'if' statement block, you could dump contents of "inFile" to a Scanner object.

```
Scanner scannedIn = new Scanner(inFile);
```

Then use the '.next' method to verify that you're accessing the file.

```
System.out.println(scannedIn.next());
```